# apt-get is stuck at "Fetched XXKb in XXsec"

Tags: apt

I tried to install crossover and after downloading the .deb from their website, I followed the steps as indicated when opening it with Ubuntu Software Centre:

> On 64-bit flavors of Debian and some Ubuntu variants, first open a
>   terminal and run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 ; sudo apt-get update`

Since I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit I perform the command.

But when copying and pasting that command into my terminal, it stopped at Fetched 535kb in 7sec and stalled there for about 20 minutes. I ended up  closing it and tried to run both commands separately but after doing the `sudo apt-get update` command it also stalls again after "Fetched XXKb in XXsec."

I restarted my computer and decided to run the software updater and it stays stuck at roughly 75% for hours.

Comment: Try setting your DNS servers to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. That fixed it for me when I had this problem.

Comment: I am currently having similar issues and it seems to be related to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325168) on the Ubuntu Forums where `appstreamcli refresh` is pegged at 100% in the processes tab and will completely max one of my cores when the update command is running which leads me to believe that this may be a bug in `appstreamcli`.

Comment: I looked at my CPU resources and core 7 is at 100% where as the other 7 are normal at like 1-2%. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can confirm the issue here, with `appstreamcli` taking 100% cpu. Killing it just makes `apt-get` fail immediately.

Comment: I had a problem similar to the one in the title, but unrelated to appstreamcli. It was solved after I rebooted the computer.

Answer (score 51):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712) and has been fixed. From a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712/comments/24) in the bug tracker, installing the following packages manually solves the problem, at least for me (the URLs are for amd64, adjust URLs for other architectures):

```
cd /tmp && mkdir asfix
cd asfix
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
cd ..
rm -r asfix
```

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with an ARM processor and this didn't work for me. I replaced amd64 with arm64, everything ok. I was able to fetch the files but then when I run `sudo apt-get update` I am always stuck

Comment: I am working in `Ubuntu 20.04` and still have this problem. Possibly this answer needs to be updated for later Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 7):

The bug has been fixed. [The packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/0.9.4-1ubuntu1) can be downloaded and installed by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the following three commands:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259142419/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259142413/gir1.2-appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259142412/appstream-index_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259142418/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb gir1.2-appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb appstream-index_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue (stuck `apt update` on 16.04, 2x `apistreamcli` at 100%), however that was not related to any particular installation.

For me it was enough to `kill -sigterm` the stuck `apistreamcli`-processes. After that `apt update && apt upgrade` worked again without issues.