# appstreamcli hanging with 100% CPU usage during update

Tags: apt, cpu-load, gnome-software, appstream

`appstreamcli` is overheating my laptop by constantly using 100% of a core. My only solution is to kill it. Here's a screenshot of [`top`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29):

[image: output of top showing appstreamcli with 100% cpu usage]

I can kill `appstreamcli` with either `sudo kill pid` or `sudo killall appstreamcli`. But once I do `sudo apt update`, the `appstreamcli` process returns again and hangs the update. If I then kill it, I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success
'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli;
 then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null;
 fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

What is this process and why is it using so much CPU?

Comment: It's a bug. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/774918/apt-get-is-stuck-at-fetched-xxkb-in-xxsec

Comment: 68 degrees is a good temperature to cook an egg, but you will need much higher temperatures to cook a laptop.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My laptop gets cooked when some dumb kernel process takes all the CPU time; it gets up to 100 degrees celcius pretty easily. Then it switches off.

Comment: @cat Right, 100 is the magic number where your laptop is cooking. Might be worth cleaning out its fan and redoing the thermal paste on its CPU.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 100 is the magic number at which the CPU says, *"I'm switching off or else I will Halt and Catch Fire!!!"*. The fan is clean and the thermal paste new, it's just old.

Comment: Is this OS X or Ubuntu ?

Comment: @SuiciDoga Probably Ubuntu with an OS X theme; I find it unlikely someone would have apt-get set up with the Ubuntu package repositories on a Mac, even if it is (theoretically) possible - it is a lot more work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 68 degrees it quite a good temperature.My laptop goes upto about 70 degrees when something hogs one core (like opening a binary file in gedit / scratch).My laptop goes upto 99 degrees sometimes

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is caused by a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712
The working solution (just tried myself):

First kill `appstreamcli`, either manually or with

```
sudo kill -KILL $(pgrep appstreamcli)
```

or

```
sudo pkill -KILL appstreamcli
```

Then:

```
wget -P /tmp https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb /tmp/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

After this you will be able to proceed with apt-get update as usual

Comment: Exactly my problem , but what is appstreamcli by the way ?

Comment: Be careful, this works on a 64-bit system; on a 32-bit, you have to change `amd64` to `i386` in the links.

Comment: To do after `sudo kill {pid}` to pass the "*dpkg status database is locked by another process*" error.

Comment: The problem is that appstreamcli is being run as root, so to bypass the database lock, just do:  sudo killall appstreamcli

Comment: Since this bug manifests itself on a very rare occasion (according to the description), the fix has to be tested through a test case. Running  `sudo appstreamcli refresh --force` without hanging will confirm that the fix works. It worked for me. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: This bug causes sudo apt-get update to fail / lock up I call this a major bug ... think about the newbies that can't use a terminal...not to mention just installing some program off a website what is this deb package doing?....ugh

Comment: I've allso found out that I had an unattedned-upgd running, which is a automatic upgarde, regarding I had all 0 in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10* so had to uninstal that as well. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively for what ever reason, if you don't want to install an out of repo package and just wait for an update you can uninstall it completely.

This will remove Discover on KDE:Plasma so I assume it will also remove the Gnome Software, or what ever your Ubuntu Flavor adds. If this is the case you can just use Muon on Kubuntu, or Synaptic on GTK based DEs.

Before you run this make sure you check the packages being removed to make sure that is ok with you.

You can figure out what something is by running

```
apt show appstream
```

to uninstall appstream run

```
sudo apt remove appstream
```