# How does Discover decide which applications it should feature?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, software-center, appstream

Kubuntu's software management suite is called *Discover* (or *plasma-discover* if you're using a terminal) and is analogous to the *Ubuntu Software Center* (or *gnome-software*). Its main panel displays a list of featured applications. How is this list generated?

Comment: According to [UbuntuSoftwareCenter - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSoftwareCenter): The “Featured Applications” option displays several applications that are popular throughout the Ubuntu community. So I guess it uses data such as how many times a particular app was downloaded across all devices and how oftenly users use it. I guess something like ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in Kubuntu 18.04, the featured applications are:

```
[
      "appstream://org.kde.krita.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.digikam.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.kdenlive.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.ktorrent.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.gcompris.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.kmymoney.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop",
      "appstream://blender.desktop",
      "appstream://inkscape.desktop",
      "appstream://org.kde.development"
    ]
```

The source for this list is [this](https://phabricator.kde.org/source/websites-autoconfig-kde-org/browse/master/discover/featured-5.9.json) according to a [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a5i4n7/eleven_months_after_kde_talks_about_polishing/ebo57wx).

Some of them can be seen in the image below:

[image: Discover's featured list]

The Reddit commenter also provided some background regarding how such a list is generated.

This is where AppStream comes in. See [What is AppStream? Why is it installed? What is it doing?](https://askubuntu.com/a/775072/248158). The data collected by AppStream includes reviews and votes on those reviews: see [this](https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2017/02/06/open-desktop-review-system-one-year-review/) and [this](https://odrs.gnome.org/) for more including what measures are taken to verify genuineness.