# 16.04 apt-get update hangs

Tags: apt, updates

Both apt-get update and upgrade hang:

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for xxx: 
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::17)]
```

I'm able to ping archive.ubuntu.com:

```
ping archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.162) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yukinko.canonical.com (91.189.88.162): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=42.2 ms
64 bytes from yukinko.canonical.com (91.189.88.162): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=42.1 ms
64 bytes from yukinko.canonical.com (91.189.88.162): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=42.1 ms
^C
--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 42.169/42.206/42.265/0.240 ms
```

I checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774986/appstreamcli-hanging-with-100-cpu-usage-during-update), and I don't think its the same issue.

Any tips for investigating this further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your output it seems to me that it's a `IPv6` problem, so we should force `apt` to use `IPv4` instead.

If we search `apt.conf (5)` manual for `IPv4` we will find:

> **ForceIPv4:**
>        When downloading, force to use only the IPv4 protocol.

To enable this option we should create a file within:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

the name can be anything for something relative 
we use `99force-ipv4`, the number is the priority of config files within this directory.

Then add the below command to this file and save it:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

Then try updating your source again:

```
sudo apt update
```

Not sure of the cause of problem, however I think your university is running an internal `IPv6` network; so `apt` is trying to connect with `IPv6` to its mirrors, and there may be some incompatibility. I just tried forcing `apt` to use `IPv4` and it worked.

**Short instruction:**

Also we can use `echo` and `tee` to write this config down with one command *[(from here)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method#100887)*:

```
echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

Comment: Ok. I'll send an email to the university IT staff to investigate further, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For me below worked:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/apt.conf

Acquire::http::proxy "http://<Proxy IPaddress>:8080/";
```