# Ubuntu apt-get update stuck at Reading package list... 0%

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am connecting via ssh to this ubuntu machine, when doing `apt-get update` it gets stuck at "**Reading package list... 0%**". Help, please.

Update: I tried installing something manually, but it won't let me neither. Also when connecting to the machine it displays "**System information disabled due to load higher than 8.0**", I checked using `top`, but there is no other process running there.

Comment: Do you have internet connection? That behaviour is usual when you do not have internet.

Comment: Yes, it has connection, I am connecting remotely to it.

Comment: Did it work before, or is it a freshly new Ubuntu installation?

Comment: It worked before, it is since today that it won't let me update or install anything.

Comment: I suppose nothing else were installed lastly... Did you try to `apt-get clean` to ensure there is no cache problem?

Comment: Yes, I already tried it.

Comment: I just found a similar problem in [linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/apt-get-update-gets-stuck-while-reading-package-list-on-my-slug-795324/), that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Could be IPv6 problem. Try running it with `sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true`

Had same problem. Found answer here: [16.04 apt-get update hangs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908649/16-04-apt-get-update-hangs)