# sudo apt-get update throwing error

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

Recently I accidentally changed the permission of all file in the root directory to world readable/writable on my ubuntu 16.04. Somehow I managed to solve the majority of the problem but stuck with wifi module. So I thought of upgrade but having the following issue with "sudo apt-get  update" commands:
[error part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYg0O.png)

[error part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMDfq.png)

[error part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mzAR.png)

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please copy and paste those errors into your question, it makes it more **search ready**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two links that you should take a look at.  The first addresses your update process:

[appstreamcli hanging with 100% CPU usage during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774986/appstreamcli-hanging-with-100-cpu-usage-during-update)

The second addresses changing the root permissions:

[What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Comment: thanks @Charles Green , first link solved the problem. thanks a lot :)